# Allocating specified strings into their own columns inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering if it is even possible to do what I want. I am right now using

```
df.loc[df.T_LOSS_DESC.str.contains("slip", na=False)]
```

It locates the column T_LOSS_DESC and then anywhere in that column where their is the specific word like "slip" it returns those rows. My first question is there anyway to put the results in its own column? also if so is their anyway to specify more than one possible keyword to look for? Example would be

```
 df.loc[df.T_LOSS_DESC.str.contains("slip,Slip,Slipped", na=False)]
```

is that viable to do? or can I only use one parameter?

what my dataframe looks like:

```
         T_LOSS_DESC 
1 Bob was running and Slipped
2 Jeff got burnt by the sun
3 James went for a walk
```

what I would like my dataframe to look like is if it finds matches inside that column I am looking at I want it to put the matches in a different column.

So my final dataframe would look like such:

```
         T_LOSS_DESC                          Slippery
1 Bob was running and Slipped        Bob was running and Slipped  
2 Jeff got burnt by the sun
3 James went for a walk
```

so since only one of my strings matched with the strings i was looking for in the column it would then bring that one match over into a new column called Slippery

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you after: `df.loc[df.T_LOSS_DESC.str.contains("slip|Slip|Slipped", na=False)]`?

Comment: Yes that works for adding multiple strings to look for, but is their someway to take the specified strings that we matched and put the instances where they were found in their own columns?

Comment: please provide a reproducible sample data set and desired data set in your question

Comment: Alright I will do that now, one moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [95]: df['new'] = df.loc[df.T_LOSS_DESC.str.contains("slip|Slip|Slipped", na=False)]

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
                   T_LOSS_DESC                          new
0  Bob was running and Slipped  Bob was running and Slipped
1    Jeff got burnt by the sun                          NaN
2        James went for a walk                          NaN
```

alternatively you can do it this way:

```
In [116]: df.loc[df.T_LOSS_DESC.str.contains("slip|Slip|Slipped", na=False), 'Slippery'] = df.T_LOSS_DESC

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
                   T_LOSS_DESC                     Slippery
0  Bob was running and Slipped  Bob was running and Slipped
1    Jeff got burnt by the sun                          NaN
2        James went for a walk                          NaN
```

Comment: I get this error: "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 46, placement implies 1"

Comment: This seems to work..... can you explain why this would work and not the other way?

Comment: @Cannon, it's hard to say, because both solutions worked fine for me when i used your sample data set